# Sort an array of strings alphabetically in groovy

Tags: arrays, sorting, input, groovy

So I have been learning to work with arrays in Groovy. I am wondering how to sort an array of strings alphabetically. My code currently takes string input from the user and prints them out in order and reverse order:

```
System.in.withReader {
    def country = []
      print 'Enter your ten favorite countries:'
    for (i in 0..9)
        country << it.readLine()
        print 'Your ten favorite countries in order/n'
    println country            //prints the array out in the order in which it was entered
        print 'Your ten favorite countries in reverse'
    country.reverseEach { println it }     //reverses the order of the array
```

How would I go about printing them out alphabetically?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`sort()` is your friend.

`country.sort()` will sort `country` alphabetically, mutating `country` in the process.
`country.sort(false)` will sort `country` alphabetically, returning the sorted list.

```
def country = ['Ireland', 'Iceland', 'Hungary', 'Thailand']
assert country.sort() == ['Hungary', 'Iceland', 'Ireland', 'Thailand']
assert country == ['Hungary', 'Iceland', 'Ireland', 'Thailand']

country = ['Ireland', 'Iceland', 'Hungary', 'Thailand']
assert country.sort(false) == ['Hungary', 'Iceland', 'Ireland', 'Thailand']
assert country == ['Ireland', 'Iceland', 'Hungary', 'Thailand']
```

Comment: Wow so simple. I am beginning to like Groovy more and more. Thank You!

Comment: If you want to sort alphabetically (i.e. case-insensitively, according to the rules of your locale) rather than just by Unicode code point, use `country.sort(java.text.Collator.instance)`.

Comment: @ataylor ooh, that's nifty!

Comment: Is there an easy way to sort alphabetically but descending (z..a) ?

Comment: @user3105453 either `.sort().reverse()` or you can use a custom closure to sort in reverse order in a single step.